# solutions of two coupled quadratic equations

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

We are given two quadratic equations
$$ 0= a x^2 + b x + c + d y $$
and
$$ 0= A y^2 + B y + C + D x $$
with real constants $a,b,c,d$ and $A, B, C, D$.

Under which conditions on the constants do (one or several) real solutions $(x,y)$ exist?

For one variable ($d=D=0$) we obtain two uncoupled equations that are solved by the standard
solution formula
$$x= \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}{2a}$$ (or the equivalent with capital constants)
such that real solutions exist if and only if the discriminant is non-negative,
$$b^2-4 a c\geq 0$$.
Is there any such criterion for two coupled equations? I understand that one can solve one equation, say the second for $y$ and substitute into the first but I am looking for a more general understanding to I can generalize to larger numbers of

linearly coupled quadratic equations, and answer under which conditions solutions exist.

Comment: There is a general theory behind this, check out [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_theorem) for more

Comment: @Moo, mentioned that in the post, I am interested in a general approach of how to discriminate equations sets of and without real solutions.